# Using negative radius buffer for ST_Buffer?

Tags: postgis

I am using postgis 2.2.

I am using ST_Buffer to my polygon and it's working for positive radius (in meters) but when i am going to apply negative radius it is showing empty values.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT    
  ST_AsGeoJSON(
      ST_Buffer(
          ST_GeomFromText(
               'POLYGON((72.89994120597838 19.070245311788284,
                         72.89981782436371 19.069915760688904,
                         72.9002845287323 19.070001951039718,
                         72.900338172912619.070341641985888,
                         72.89991974830626 19.07023517176424,
                         72.89994120597838 19.070245311788284)
               )', 4326)
       ,-3.024)
  ) as geometry;
```

The Results are :

```
      geometry
-------------------------------------
 {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[]}
(1 row)
```

How to apply negative buffer (-10 meters) to polygon (in meters)?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty values because your buffer param is too high, as (from postgis docs) "Calculations are in the Spatial Reference System of this Geometry".

You can use this function
`geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer_in_meters);`
replacing `ST_GeomFromText(WKT, SRID)` with `ST_GeogFromText(WKT)`